# How to destack nested tuples in Python?

Tags: python, nested, tuples

How to convert the following  tuple:

from:

```
(('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), 'dd')
```

to:

```
('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/989121 for more general solutions

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
l = (('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), 'dd')
l = l[0] + (l[1],)
```

This will work for your situation, however [John La Rooy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745275/1907098) is better for general cases.

Comment: I want to achieve the following : `a , b = (12 , 21)  , (1,2)`   . I want to get a third tuple `c = ( (12,21), (1,2) ) ` .How to do this?

Answer (score 46):

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)

x = a + b

print(x)
```

Out:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: NB: This answers the title of the question, but not its body. The title of the question should have been "How to destack nested tuples" instead.

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> tuple(j for i in (('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), 'dd') for j in (i if isinstance(i, tuple) else (i,)))
('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
```

Comment: `def merge_tuples(*t): return tuple(j for i in (t) for j in (i if isinstance(i, tuple) else (i,)))` to make it more generic.

Answer (score 8):

```
x = (('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), 'dd')
tuple(list(x[0]) + [x[1]])
```

Comment: `x[0] + (x[1],)` is fine too

Answer (score 3):

```
l = (('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), 'dd')
```

You can simply do:

```
(*l[0], l[1])
```

Result:

```
('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
```